# use elements in a sub-stream and, using each element of the stream, create another object, and finally return list of objects created in higher stream

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-stream

I am trying to create a Elasticsearch java API `bulkRequest` for products. `bulkRequest` accepts list of operations and for creating each operation we need to pass a product object (product element of products list). Not able to do it using the functional interface.

Syntax of creating the operations are as:

```java
/**
 * Required - Request body.
 * <p>
 * API name: {@code _value_body}
 * <p>
 * Adds a value to <code>operations</code> using a builder lambda.
 */
public final Builder operations(Function<BulkOperation.Builder, ObjectBuilder<BulkOperation>> fn) {
    return operations(fn.apply(new BulkOperation.Builder()).build());
}
```

Overloaded method of creating the operations are as:

```java
public final Builder operations(List<BulkOperation> list) {
    this.operations = _listAddAll(this.operations, list);
    return this;
}
```

If I use below code, then it works fine

```java
BulkResponse bulkResponse = esUtil.bulkIndex(new BulkRequest.Builder().index(INDEX_NAME)
                    .operations(products.stream().map(p -> new BulkOperation.Builder()
                            .index(new IndexOperation.Builder<>().document(p).id(String.valueOf(p.getId())).build()).build()).toList())
                    .build());
```

Problem which I am facing is that I am not able to create `operations` builder that accepts the List of `Index operation` and each `index operation` is created using the `product` object.

If I use below code, it compiles fine but returns `ClassCastException` runtime.

```
BulkResponse bulkResponse = esUtil.bulkIndex(new BulkRequest.Builder().index(INDEX)
                            .operations(bo -> (ObjectBuilder<BulkOperation>) products.stream().map(
                                    p -> bo.index(io-> io.document(p).id(String.valueOf(p.Id()))))
                                    ).build());
```

**Let me know if further information or clarification required. Not an expert in Java stream and in functional programming here.**

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using loops.

Comment: @Bohemian thanks for your reply, I can do it using loops, but would be better if I can do the same using lambda as it would be more concise and new learning for me, and I need this at several places in my code.

Comment: Well, obviously, the problem is the cast to `ObjectBuilder<BulkOperation>`. When the expression doesn’t evaluate to a `ObjectBuilder<BulkOperation>`, you can’t cast it to `ObjectBuilder<BulkOperation>` and expect it to somehow turn into a `ObjectBuilder<BulkOperation>`. Part of the problem is that this code is unreadable; it’s just impossible to guess and then remember, which closing bracket belongs to which opening bracket with these seven or eight levels of nesting and the nonmatching formatting.

Comment: @Holger totally agree with you, its not readable, but this is how Elasticsearch new java client is designed, I posted same question to their forum and their team member suggested changes like this https://github.com/spinscale/elasticsearch-rest-client-samples/blob/main/src/main/java/de/spinscale/restclient/ProductServiceImpl.java#L73-L94

Comment: @Holger if you want I can format the code to be more readable, also I like the way Elastic team member created it using same product example, only this which i don't like is the use of for loop inside lambda, can we avoid for loop completely.

Comment: Well, when there are no checked exceptions involved, you can simply change `for (Product product : products) { … }` to `products.forEach(product -> { … } );`. The second loop uses the loop index; it would be possible to rewrite it using an `IntStream.range(…)`, but I’d stay with the loop.